# 100% height child div in parent wrap div

Tags: html, css

Im here because other similar questions couldn't help my particular problem.

How can #right div height making 100% ? 
Only css solution needing. Thanks.

[http://jsfiddle.net/elturko/86nX9/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29hC0.png)

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrap">
 <div id="header"></div>
 <div id="left"></div>
 <div id="right"></div>
 <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#wrap{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background:#ddd
}
#header{
    height:104px;
    background:#d5a1b3;
}
#left{
    float:left;
    width:219px;
    background:#a2d025;
}
#right{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#FFF;
    margin:0 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding:14px;
}
#footer{ 
    clear:both;
    height:15px;
    background:#ed653a;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Here's 2 Pure CSS solution

Without fixing any height (header/footer) or width (left column).

I actually prefer the second solution. (even tho he has less browser support)

### 1 - using CSS tricks

this is a totally responsive design and work well with all browsers (IE10, FF, Chrome, Safari, Opera, mobile browsers)

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/eEFBh/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="Container">
    <div class="Header">
    </div>
    <div class="HeightTaker">
        <div class="Wrapper Container Inverse">
            <div>
                <div class="Footer">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="HeightTaker">
                <div class="Wrapper">
                    <div class="LeftMenu">
                    </div>
                    <div class="Content">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body, .Container
{
    height: 100%;
}
    .Container:before
    {
        content: '';
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
    }
.HeightTaker
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
    .HeightTaker:after
    {
        content: '';
        clear: both;
        display: block;
    }
.Wrapper
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.Inverse, .Inverse > *
{
    -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.LeftMenu
{
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.Content
{
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

/*For demonstration only*/
p
{    
    font-size: 1.3em;
}

.Important
{
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: white;
}

body > .Container
{
    text-align: center;
}

.Header
{
    background-color: #bf5b5b;
}
.LeftMenu
{
    background-color:  #bdbe4c;
}

.Content
{
    background-color: #90adc1;
}
.Footer
{
    background-color: #b5a8b7;
}
```

### 2 - using Flex

This layout can also be achieved using flex, but the current browser support is pure.
Here's a [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/6Mp4g/1/) **only** FF,Chrome,IE10.

**HTML:** (simpler)

```
<header>
</header>
<section class="Middle">
    <div class="LeftMenu">
    </div>
    <div class="Content">
    </div>
</section>
<footer>
</footer>
```

**CSS:**

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

body
{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.Middle
{    
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 0;

    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;

    overflow: hidden;
}

.Content
{   
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 0 0;

    overflow: auto;
}

/*For demonstration only*/
p
{    
    font-size: 1.3em;
}

.Important
{
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: white;
}

header
{
    background-color: #bf5b5b;
}
.LeftMenu
{
    background-color:  #bdbe4c;
}

.Content
{
    background-color: #90adc1;
}
footer
{
    background-color: #b5a8b7;
}
```

Comment: ok i'm marked. when inside .Content div writing long contents this time scrool not working properly. 
.footer div fixed position stay. but general amazing code. maybe i try with jQuery!.

Answer (score 1):

Take this out of css for `#right{}` :

```
margin:0 15px;
```

This will make it wide 100%. I'm a little confused on the 100% height. Did you meant wide?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/elturko/86nX9/
here i remove margin:0 15px; but not change anything.

Comment: block level elements (which divs are) default to 100% container width

Answer (score 0):

Important will over-ride other CSS attributes and auto will make the div as large as it needs to be to fit the contents.

```
height: auto !important; 
height: 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#right{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#FFF;
    margin:0 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding:14px;

    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Add `top: 0px; bottom: 0px;` to your `#right` css

Comment: try setting to position: absolute

Answer (score 0):

I restructured your html a bit. Is that your desired outcome?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/86nX9/20/)

```
<div id="container">
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">
        header
    </div>

    <div id="body">
        <div id="left">
            left
        </div>

        <div id="right">
            right<br>
            right<br>
            right<br>
            right<br>
            right<br>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <p>footer</p>
</div>
```

css

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#container {
    height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#wrap {
    overflow: auto;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
}

#header {
    height: 104px;
    background:#d5a1b3;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

#body {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

#right {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 220px;
    background:#FFF;
}

#left {
    width: 219px;
    float: left;
    background:#a2d025;
}

#footer {
    background:#ed653a;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: -21px;
    clear: both;
}
#footer p {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: sorry but i need #right radius and margin... this idea not my solution.