# Issue with overlapping DIV (and image)

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem with an overlapping DIV.

This is how the webpage appears when the window is maximised[image: This is how the webpage appears when the window is maximised]

This is how the webpage appears when the window is shrunk[image: This is how the webpage appears when the window is shrunk]

[image: This is how the webpage appears when the user scrolls to the right (red arrow) to view the text/image] This is how the webpage appears when the user scrolls to the right (red arrow) to view the text/image but the problem is that the content overlaps the side bar (blue arrow).

So my question is, how do stop this happening (or how should I be doing this)?

This is my HTML/CSS (it's not in a Fiddle because I can't demonstrate the issue that way)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html><head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<title>Example Title</title>
<style>
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

.content {
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    clear: right;
}
#sidebar #menubar li, #sidebar #menubar li:link, #sidebar #menubar li:visited {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
#sidebar #menubar li a, #sidebar #menubar li a:link, #sidebar #menubar li a:visited {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;   font-size: 80%;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#logo {
    height: 90px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

#sidebar #menubar li:hover {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    background-color: #06C;
}
#sidebar #menubar li a:hover {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;   font-size: 80%;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#sidebar    #menubar li#active{
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;   
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    background-color: #0066CC;
}

#sidebar #menubar  {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
h1 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 125%;
    color: #006;
    text-decoration: none;
}html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    float:left;
    background-color: #006;
    padding-top: 25px;
    position: fixed;
    clear: right;
    overflow-y:auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    bottom: 0px;
}

#content {
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 250px;
    padding-top: 125px;
    padding-right: 125px;
    padding-bottom: 125px;
    padding-left: 125px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
 #sidebar{
    position:relative;
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    clear: right;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
  }
#content {
    position:relative;
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 25px;
    clear: right;
}

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<section><div id="sidebar">
<div id="logo"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x89/000/fff&text=Logo" width="200" height="89" alt="" /></div>
<ul id="menubar">
      <li ><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
       <li ><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li ><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      <li ><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      <li ><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>

    </ul> 
    </div></section>
<div id="content">
<div class="content">
<h1>Example H1</h1>
   <p>Duis aliquam mauris ac felis tincidunt varius. Maecenas pharetra id risus sed adipiscing. Vestibulum non libero eu quam semper commodo. Aliquam et diam ac tortor molestie blandit. Nullam et sem elit. Aenean tincidunt vitae lacus luctus fringilla. Cras mattis placerat semper. Etiam ullamcorper nunc vel mauris suscipit feugiat. In ac sollicitudin tellus, quis condimentum velit. Sed aliquam, leo non luctus dignissim, sapien felis ultrices sapien, vitae sollicitudin tortor sapien viverra diam. Nam varius nulla sapien, in pharetra sem placerat pretium. Ut varius vehicula nisl vel scelerisque. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed iaculis, risus condimentum accumsan sagittis, mauris sem accumsan lectus, interdum porta metus leo sit amet tortor. 
</p>
   <div class="content-image"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/650x400/000/fff&text=Large+Image" alt="" width="650" height="400" border="0" align="middle" /></div>
 </div>
</div>
<div style='clear:both;'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: The reason why the side bar has a position: fixed is because this happens if it isn't:

[image: Edit]

Comment: where do you want the image to go when the user scrolls right?

Comment: I'd quite like it so that it doesn't overlap the side bar. So when the user scrolls right, it would be quite useful if the whole page scrolls right (including the side bar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The side bar needs to have a position absolute, give this a read: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

```
  <!DOCTYPE html><head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<title>Example Title</title>
<style>
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

.content {
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    clear: right;
}
#sidebar #menubar li, #sidebar #menubar li:link, #sidebar #menubar li:visited {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
#sidebar #menubar li a, #sidebar #menubar li a:link, #sidebar #menubar li a:visited {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;   font-size: 80%;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#logo {
    height: 90px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

#sidebar #menubar li:hover {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    background-color: #06C;
}
#sidebar #menubar li a:hover {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;   font-size: 80%;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#sidebar    #menubar li#active{
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;   
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    background-color: #0066CC;
}

#sidebar #menubar  {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
h1 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 125%;
    color: #006;
    text-decoration: none;
}html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    float:left;
    background-color: #006;
    padding-top: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    clear: right;
    overflow-y:auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    bottom: 0px;
}

#content {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 700px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 250px;
    padding-top: 125px;
    padding-right: 125px;
    padding-bottom: 125px;
    padding-left: 125px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
 #sidebar{
    position:relative;
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    clear: right;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
  }
#content {
    position:relative;
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 25px;
    clear: right;
}
.content img {
    display: none;
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<section><div id="sidebar">
<div id="logo"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x89/000/fff&text=Logo" width="200" height="89" alt="" /></div>
<ul id="menubar">
      <li ><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
       <li ><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li ><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      <li ><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      <li ><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>

    </ul> 
    </div></section>
<div id="content">
<div class="content">
<h1>Example H1</h1>
   <p>Duis aliquam mauris ac felis tincidunt varius. Maecenas pharetra id risus sed adipiscing. Vestibulum non libero eu quam semper commodo. Aliquam et diam ac tortor molestie blandit. Nullam et sem elit. Aenean tincidunt vitae lacus luctus fringilla. Cras mattis placerat semper. Etiam ullamcorper nunc vel mauris suscipit feugiat. In ac sollicitudin tellus, quis condimentum velit. Sed aliquam, leo non luctus dignissim, sapien felis ultrices sapien, vitae sollicitudin tortor sapien viverra diam. Nam varius nulla sapien, in pharetra sem placerat pretium. Ut varius vehicula nisl vel scelerisque. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed iaculis, risus condimentum accumsan sagittis, mauris sem accumsan lectus, interdum porta metus leo sit amet tortor. 
</p>
   <div class="content-image"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/650x400/000/fff&text=Large+Image" alt="" width="650" height="400" border="0" align="middle" /></div>
 </div>
</div>
<div style='clear:both;'></div>
</body>
```

Comment: set thew body height to 100%

Comment: If you take a look at the CSS, I've already set the height to 100%

`}html, body {
 height:100%;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 background-color: #FFF;
}`

Comment: I've also tried adding the normalize css which you suggested but I still have the same issue with maintaining the height of the scroll bar.

If I set the image width to 100% however (in img src not css) then I don't have this issue. The problem is that that method is not compatible with some browsers e.g. ie8, which requires a height to be defined.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412618/100-height-child-div-in-parent-wrap-div

Comment: take a look at the link i posted it'll help you :D

Answer (score 1):

This is because the sidebar is fixed. To achieve what you want, try floating both the sidebar and the content to the left.

Here's a simplified example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZJsQz/)

```
#sidebar
{
    float:left;
    background-color:#56B7BF;
    width:150px;
    height:400px;
}
#content
{
    float:left;
    background-color:#BF5E56;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
}
```